# Unable to center recyclerview item

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

In order to make my recyclerview adapter more dynamic I programmatically have set the width to be a certain percentage.  But I cannot now center the items, appears hardcoding margin in the XML for the recyclerview item works, but this is not ideal.  Appears "android:gravity" is not an available attribute on recyclerview.  android:layout_gravity anywhere doesnt seem to work.  I though that I would try in my "ViewHolder.from(parent).apply to programmatically add padding but I get an error "Val cannot be reassigned"
[image: picture1]

Im out of ideas at this point, any help?  Im using constraintLayout for my recyclerview item.

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder.from(parent).apply {
            val targetWidth = parent.measuredWidth * .9
            itemView.layoutParams.width = targetWidth.toInt()
        }
    }
```

My Adapter code

```
package com.example.recyclerview_2.view

import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.core.view.marginEnd
import androidx.core.view.marginStart
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.AsyncDifferConfig
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ListAdapter
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.recyclerview_2.R
import com.example.recyclerview_2.databinding.RecyclerviewItemBinding
import com.example.recyclerview_2.model.models.Bill
import com.example.recyclerview_2.utils.Format
import kotlin.reflect.KFunction1

private const val TAG = "Adapter"
class Adapter(private val itemClickListener: KFunction1<Bill, Unit>) : ListAdapter<Bill, Adapter.ViewHolder>(AsyncDifferConfig.Builder<Bill>(DiffCallBack()).build()) {

    //When a inner keyword is used here you cannot create a companion object
    //When the 'inner' keyword is used members of the outer class are all accessible
    class ViewHolder(val binding: RecyclerviewItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {



        fun bind(data: Bill, itemClickListener: () -> Unit){
            binding.billName.text = data.name.replaceFirstChar {
                it.uppercase()
            }
            binding.billAmt.text = Format.addTrailingZeros(data.amount) + "$"
            binding.dateDue = data.dateDue
            if(data.reoccurring){
                binding.reoccurring = data.reoccurringInterval
            }else{
                binding.billReoccuring.text = "Bill is not reoccurring"
            }
            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                Log.d("ClickED","${data._id}")
                itemClickListener()
            }
        }
        companion object{
            fun from(parent: ViewGroup): ViewHolder {
                var layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                var binding = RecyclerviewItemBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
                return ViewHolder(binding)
            }
        }

    }

    private class DiffCallBack : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Bill>(){
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Bill, newItem: Bill): Boolean = oldItem._id == newItem._id

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Bill, newItem: Bill): Boolean = oldItem == newItem

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder.from(parent).apply {
            val targetWidth = parent.measuredWidth * .9
            itemView.layoutParams.width = targetWidth.toInt()
        }
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
                val item = currentList[position]
                holder.bind(item, { itemClickListener(item) })
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return currentList.size
    }

}
```

[image: picture2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LayoutManager` is what handles how item views are arranged in the `RecyclerView`. You should probably just design your item layout (the one you inflate for the `ViewHolder`) to have its contents centred, i.e. the main layout with width `wrap_content`, then the stuff *inside that* arranged how you want it. This also gives you more flexibility, since it doesn't mean *everything* has to be centred.

If you want your content to take up 90% of the width, you could use a `ConstraintLayout` with [`Guideline`s](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/constraint-layout#constrain-to-a-guideline) at 5% and 95% and constrain stuff to that. You could also nest another layout inside that main layout, and constrain its width with `layout_constraintWidth_percent` set to *0.9* (90% of the parent's width) - personally I feel like that's more limiting (instead of having one flat layout) but it's up to you.

Remember you can add plain `View`s if you need a *"content area"* with a background, and stick that behind the other views - they don't *need* to be inside another layout!

Comment: This makes sense, I was taking the wrong approach.  Super helpful, thank you so much for your comment:)